# using date in git bash commit message

Tags: bash, git, windows-10, git-bash

I am using a `.bat` file in windows 10 to push changes to an external repo, I have the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
cd C:\path\to\my\repo
set timestamp=$(date +"%D %T")

git add .
git commit -m "Backup at: `%timestamp%`" 
git push origin master
git pull origin master
```

What I want to do is have the commit message be `"Backup at: date"` but it just makes it `` "Backup at: `$(date +T)\`" ``
Is there a way I can fix this to make it the date?

Comment: what does ``%timestamp%`` suppose to do?, validate your script at http://shllcheck.net

Comment: You could try executing your commands one at a time to see if they do what you want.  Hint: at least half of those don't do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your script as a regular bash shell script since Windows executes `.sh` files using Git Bash.

So write it like this:

**Example:** `myBackup.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /c/path/to/repo
timestamp=$(date +%c)
git add .
git commit -m "Backup at: $timestamp"
git push origin master
echo Press Enter...
read
```

---

- `$(date +%c)` Will give you the locale date and time (e.g., Sun, Mar 15, 2020 12:01:53 AM) Use `date --help` to see full options. no need for `set`
- Use variable like `$timestamp` not `%timestamp%` and without the backticks (``` `` ```)
- <s>Use Forward slash `/` not Backslash `\`</s> Backslash works on Windows.

Comment: It seems the OP is in windows, so using \ in the PATH is correct.